# I want to embed pdf file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show pdf file in my website and my friends tell me about this method and all communities also tell me this method

```
 <body>
    <embed src="files/oldEhsa.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
  </body>
```

But when i use this code and open my website it start to download my pdf file not show it

what is wrong i might have done ?

Comment: embed plugins have been removed and are nomore supported by most of modern browsers, so it's unlikely you will be able to do what you want that way. You can use PDF.js or one of the many libraries based on PDF.js  https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfobject .

Comment: What browsers are you using, You can only preview embedded PDFs if the browser has a PDF viewer plugin. Most desktop browsers will display them for you. Most mobile browsers do not have a plugin and will download it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `<object>` or `<iframe>` instead:

```html
<body>
    <object data="files/oldEhsa.pdf" />
</body>
```

```html
<body>
    <iframe src="files/oldEhsa.pdf" />
</body>
```

To change the dimensions of your embed, use the `width` or `height` attributes.